# How to get values of all rows in JTable and split them with delimiters and newline?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Say I had a table like this:

```
|ID|Name|Work|Age|
|31|John|IT  |31 |
|32|Jane|IT  |22 |
```

And I wanted to convert the values in the cell to string with delimiters(,) and newline like this:

```
31,John,IT ,31 
32,Jane,IT ,22
```

What code would I need to punch in in order for this to happen?

Comment: Do you have a personal TableModel?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a minimal reproducible example. For more information, please see How to Ask and take the tour.

Answer (score 0):

The following method convert a `JTable` in CSV String

```
public static String exportToCSV(JTable tableToExport) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    TableModel model = tableToExport.getModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            stringBuilder.append(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString()).append(",");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```